# Where is the combining PDF file?

Tags: python, pypdf

I have a problem and need your help.
I learn Python with "Automate the boring stuff with Python". I am currently at chapter 13, dealing with PDF files and Word documents.
I have these code from the book.It basically combine pdf file without their first page. But after I run the program, I didn't see any PDF file pop up. I try to find it in the directory but it is not there neither.
So help me find that file, thank you!
Here 's the code

```
import PyPDF2
import os
pdfFiles = []
for filename in os.listdir('.'):
if filename.endswith('.pdf'):
    pdfFiles.append(filename)
pdfFiles.sort(key=str.lower)
pdfWriter = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()
or filename in pdfFiles:
pdfFileObj = open(filename, 'rb')
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
for pageNum in range(1, pdfReader.numPages):
    pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(pageNum)
    pdfWriter.addPage(pageObj)
pdfOutput = open('allminutes.pdf', 'wb')
pdfWriter.write(pdfOutput)
pdfOutput.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some missing indentation, typo in the code. After fixing that, I can merge two PDF files as expected.

**Update**

As you are not able to get the output PDF file yet, let's check if it is really created by displaying the merged PDF file's number of pages.

I am using an input folder for my input PDF files (which is `input_files`).

`merge_pdfs.py` iterates over all PDF files in `input_files` and merged them to `allminutes.pdf` by skipping the first pages of each PDF files.

Before running the code, folder structure:

```
├── input_files
│   ├── module.pdf
│   └── pypi.pdf
├── merge_pdfs.py
├── requirements.txt
└── screenshots
    └── demo_output.png
```

After running the code, folder structure:

```
├── allminutes.pdf
├── input_files
│   ├── module.pdf
│   └── pypi.pdf
├── merge_pdfs.py
├── requirements.txt
└── screenshots
    └── demo_output.png
```

`merge_pdfs.py`:

```
import PyPDF2
import os
pdfFiles = []
outputFile = 'allminutes.pdf'
inputFileDirectory = 'input_files'
for filename in os.listdir(inputFileDirectory):
    if filename.endswith('.pdf'):
        pdfFiles.append(inputFileDirectory+os.sep+filename)
    pdfFiles.sort(key=str.lower)
    pdfWriter = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()
    for filename in pdfFiles:
        pdfFileObj = open(filename, 'rb')
        pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
        for pageNum in range(1, pdfReader.numPages):
            pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(pageNum)
            pdfWriter.addPage(pageObj)
        pdfOutput = open(outputFile, 'wb')
        pdfWriter.write(pdfOutput)
        pdfOutput.close()
print("Done merging the pdf files to {}".format(outputFile))

pdfFile = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(open(outputFile, "rb"))
# print how many pages outputFile has:
print("{} has {} pages.".format(outputFile, pdfFile.getNumPages()))
```

Generated `allminutes.pdf` file:

[image: allminutes.pdf]

Output of `merge_pdfs.py`:

```
Done merging the pdf files to allminutes.pdf
allminutes.pdf has 4 pages.
```

Comment: So in my case, after write the right code into Pycharm, I just need to "Run" the program and this PDF file appear right. I ask because I fixed my code like yours and nothing happened.

Comment: No.Just nothing happened except for the line "Process finished with exit code 0". I usually see when a code have no error.

Comment: And could you explain further for me about why the merge_pdfs.py is the program above and it is included in the allminutes.pdf.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: Damn! You do put a lot of time into this instruction. It works and is easy to comprehend. I 'm appreciated. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I put a lot of time answering this. I am glad it works :)